# MDX How to calculate the Avg/Sum of last 36 Month

Tags: sql-server, mdx, analysis

```
WITH 
  MEMBER AvgOfLast36Month AS 
    Sum
    (
      LastPeriods
      (2
       ,[Dim Date].[Month].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[capacity]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {AvgOfLast36Month} ON 0
 ,{[Project].[Model].[Model]} ON 1
FROM [CubeCapacity]
WHERE 
  StrToSet('[Dim Date].[Date].&[2014-02-20T00:00:00]&[02]&[1]&[2014]');
```

I am trying to sum the last 36 month Avg capacity. I did'nt get the accurate total. can anybody please help me

Comment: people will help you if you put some more details in the question. for a start, show some sample data and desired output and describe your problem in a bit more detail, otherwise this question will be closed as off topic, as you're effectively saying "why isn't this code working?"

Comment: you want the daily average for each of the past 36 months, summed together?

Comment: Do you have any date hierarchy in cube, sort of like year-quarter-month-date? Answers and performance can be much better in that case

Answer (score 0):

I believe this expression returns the *Sum*:

```
  MEMBER AvgOfLast36Month AS 
    Sum
    (
      LastPeriods
      (2
       ,[Dim Date].[Month].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[capacity]
    )
```

`MDX` have and `AVG` function - better to try using that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146067.aspx

This section of your script is filtering down the context and causing the problem:

```
WHERE 
  StrToSet('[Dim Date].[Date].&[2014-02-20T00:00:00]&[02]&[1]&[2014]');
```

Maybe you could move this dynamic `strTo..` snippet to the `WITH` clause? This advWrks script is an example:

```
WITH 
  SET [x] AS 
    LastPeriods
    (36
     ,Exists
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,StrToMember('[Date].[Date].&[20070713]')
      ).Item(0).Item(0)
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[avgOverSet] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [x]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[avgOverSet]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [x] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The following is has country on rows:

```
WITH 
  SET [36mth] AS 
    LastPeriods
    (36
     ,Exists
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
       ,StrToMember('[Date].[Date].&[20070713]')
      ).Item(0).Item(0)
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[avgOver36mths] AS 
    Avg
    (
      [36mth]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[avgOver36mths]} ON 0
 ,[Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```